# Constants becoming undefined in included file

Tags: php

```
<?php
define("URL", "http://localhost/framework/");
require_once URL.'config.php';
require_once URL.'library/standardObjects/foundation.php';
?>
```

However, when I use the URL constant inside of the foundation.php file it throws a notice:use of undefined constant.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because One does not `include` source codes over `HTTP`!  (PHP will send output to you then, not the source code)

```
define("URL", "/directory/name/here");  // not an HTTP url
```

Your code that you included is not really included and is not available to the scripts below. Your `supposedly` included files are loading over HTTP and of course they cant see your Constant.